# advantages of row vs column data representation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, row

I am writing a MATLAB toolbox and I need to store a moderately large number of vector-valued data points (10^4 to 10^5).
I can store these data points in a D-by-N matrix or a N-by-D matrix, where D is the dimensionality of the data and N the total number of data points.

Many MATLAB functions assume a N-by-D representation (e.g., `cov`, `kmeans`), so I assume that it is the default representation and I would follow it.

**Is there *any* reason to favour the D-by-N representation in MATLAB instead?**

I am asking because I have seen quite a number of people using the D-by-N representation in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB uses [column-major](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Row-major_order) representation of matrices. This means that the consecutive values in memory go down the columns. This also matches MATLAB's linear indexing. So if you have an `N`-by-`D` matrix, `M`, then the elements `M(x,y)` and `M(x+1,y)` are stored in consecutive memory slots whereas `M(x,y)` and `M(x,y+1)` are `N` solts away from each other in memory. So if you wanted to extract all the data points for a feature then using an `N`-by-`D` configuration means that all those data points are stored consecutively in memory where-as if you wanted to exract all the features for a single observation, then they would not be (but would be in a `D`-by-`N`). So the question is what are you more likely to do? Bare in mind that typical MATLAB functions operate on the rows by default so is you were to go `mean(M)`, you would get the average values for each dimension in the `N`-by-`D` case but you would get the average for a single observation across dimensions in the `D`-by-`N` case which I would think is far less likely to be a useful measure.

The case for `D`-by-`N` however might come down to linear algebra. If you are going to do matrix multiplications on your data (which many vectorized algorithms do do), then you probably want to store them in a way that will minimise the number of times you will need to transpose those data. I suspect that this is why you have seen `D`-by-`N` representations, because `M` will be used in a linear algebra formula that expects `D`-by-`N` and thus avoids a transpose.

Comment: Thanks, great reply.  The linear algebra rationale makes total sense.